# Is there a way to sort a set of co-ordinates in a top-to-bottom, left-to-right precedence as they appear?

Tags: python, math, geometry, coordinates

I have a list of XY co-ordinates, and I am looking for a way to sort them as they appear on the plot with top-to-bottom, left-to-right precedence.

I tried sorting them as a tuple in Python but it didn't work.

Here are the (normalized) co-ordinates:

(0.48425699105850684, 0.4852200502470339)
(0.8003207976544613, 0.1794844315136523)
(0.663158173206857, 0.19739922702645016)
(0.26770425263394393, 0.20288883507443173)
(0.5214529814719886, 0.2032096846467844)
(0.4768268032594222, 0.3875097802042241)
(0.5400594055964151, 0.5870619715600098)
(0.5445470099105095, 0.8064964338255158)

Comment: Reverse each tuple while sorting.

Comment: Keep in mind that this is basically just vertical sort for floats

Answer (score 1):

So you need to use Y-coordinate as primary key, X-coordinate as secondary key.
One of possible ways in Python:

```
lst.sort(key = lambda x: (x[1], x[0]))
```

if your Y-axis direction is down (otherwise `-x[1]`)

Example:

```
lst = [(3, 8), (5, 3), (1, 5), (2, 3), (7, 4), (4, 5)]
lst.sort(key = lambda x: (x[1], x[0]))
print(lst)

>>[(2, 3), (5, 3), (7, 4), (1, 5), (4, 5), (3, 8)]
```

Comment: Maybe `x[::-1]`?

Comment: @Olvin Roght There is a lot of approaches. I am not sure how coordinate axes are oriented, so left the opportunity to inverse one of them

Comment: Hey I tried this but it did not work, thanks for the response!

Comment: @fortyTwo102 But I tried and it does work. provides order like strings in text  . See example

Answer (score 0):

I eventually ended up using the product of the X and Y coordinates as the sorting key. It worked for my test cases!

Comment: This approach gives rather exotic point ordering.